# .log files are getting generated when using karate-core dependency

Tags: logging, karate, scenarios

I'm currently using karate-core dependency of version 1.2.0. Using this dependency, ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1.log these log files are getting generated. If i use karate-apache dependency, then it is generating these .log file in the target folder. Is there any way i can generate these log files using karate-core dependency? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These log files were always internal to Karate and you were not supposed to depend on them. Please assume that what you want in not supported.